# Regular expression in Visual Studio for renaming logging method parameter strings?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I'm very curious to know the regular expression to replace:

```
MyLog.LogFatal("Error E20111205-1147. Custom error.\n");
```

with this:

```
MyLog.LogFatal("{0}Error E20111205-1147. Custom error.\n",TPrefix(this));
```

It has to work for any error number, i.e. E12345678-1234.

**Update**

I should have clarified my question: I want to alter my C# source code, within Visual Studio, using the "Find..Find and Replace..Quick Replace" (Ctrl-H) command. There is about 1,000 instances of this message in my C# source code tree, and it would take too long to edit it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: Updated solution, complete Regex is**

Starting with:

```
MyLog.LogFatal("Error E20111205-1147. Custom error.\n");
```

Find Expression:

```
// Matches MyLog.LogFatal(" {any text with 0-9, a-z, A-Z, space, -, . character 
//   and terminated by \n"} "); 
// Hence, the captured expression from your example is 
//   Error E20111205-1147. Custom error.\n"
MyLog.LogFatal\(\"{[0-9a-zA-Z -\\\.]+\\n\"}\);
```

Replace Expression:

```
// Replaces MyLog.LogFatal("{0} {your captured expression}, TPrefix(this));
MyLog.LogFatal(\"{0}\1, TPrefix(this));
```

You Get:

```
MyLog.LogFatal("{0}Error E20111205-1147. Custom error.\n", TPrefix(this));
```

For an introduction to VS2010 Regex Find and replace, please see this [blog post](http://goo.gl/Ve0sd).

Comment: Brilliant, just brilliant - this worked like a charm. Now my project still compiles, and everything is updated. You've saved me days of work. Thank you!

Comment: @Gravitas very welcome and thanks for the answer :) I just blogged about this at http://goo.gl/Ve0sd . So happens I was working on a Regex Find and replace just before seeing this Q hence was in the regex mood. lol

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the actual "log text" was just an example and in reality you have different messages:

Find what:

> MyLog\.LogFatal\("{.+}"\);

Replace with:

> MyLog.LogFatal("{0}\1", TPrefix(this));

**UPDATE** Dang! Only just found out that "Blockquote" suppresses single slashes.

Comment: I'm going to +1 this as it also works. Sportsmanship n' all that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
{MyLog.[A-Za-z]+\("}{Error E[^ ]+\..*}\);
```

Replace the first capture with

```
`\1{0}\2,TPrefix(this));`
```

This will also find MyLog.LogWarning, MyLog.LogError. If you don't want that, remove [A-Za-z] with LogFatal.

Explanation of the regex:

- `{....}` first and second captured group, captures `MyLog.LogFatal("` (including quote), these are `\1` and `\2` in the replacement expression
- `[A-Za-z]+` captures any keyword that only contains of A-Z and a-z characters, the `+` means one or more
- `\(` you must escape parenthesis
- `E[^ ]+` starting with an `E` and then *not* containing spaces
- `\.` and ending with a dot (you must escape the dot, otherwise it means *any character*).
- `.*` everything till end of the line

---

Alternatively, if the logmessage is more different, but you know the MyLog.XXX calls, you can also use the following, to only captre the ones that contain a snippet of the form E##### (where # is any digit). Replacement expression remains the same as above.

```
{MyLog.Log(Debug|Warning|Error|Fatal)\("}{.*E[0-9-]+\..*}\);
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation on how RegEx works in Visual Studio, I've always struggled with this and I think I'm starting to get it now.

Comment: @Gravitas, glad to be of help. Note that for the larger part, VS regexes work just like any other regex (see http://regular-expressions.info). A few exceptions, the most notable being `{...}` to capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="Error E20111205-1147. Custom error.\n";
Regex re=new Regex("^Error E\\d{8}-\\d{4}\\. Custom error\\.\\n$");
if (re.Matches(s).Count>0) s=String.Format("{0}{1}",TPrefix(this),s);
```

Comment: So this is the reason, why it has the C# tag?

Comment: Because it asks about going through C# code using Visual Studio Search & Replace using regular expressions. The question is quite clear on that.