# Dynamical logging framework or technique

Tags: c#, dynamic, logging

I wanted to ask for some logging mechanism or framework with specific function. I am already loggin in my app (dll library) with

```
Log.WriteLine("{0}.{1}()", System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

where the Log is static class with capability to write to file using Streamwriter

```
public void LogWriteLine(string text, params object[] args) {
  lock (this) {
      StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter(logFile, true);
      if (log != null) {
        log.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {1}", DateTime.Now, String.Format(text, args));
        log.Flush();
        log.Close();
      }
  }
}
```

My problem is, I don't have the `Log.WriteLine` call all over my app, just in specific parts of apps, because it would create really big file. But now, I build my app, and posted it to the developers, they worked on it for some days. After that they send me bugs, but in my version the bugs are not anymore (the development continues on the app, so they could be fixed).

So I wanted to have in the app some setting file, to tell the app that I need more logs and be able to run the testers version of app without to rebuild it just with different settings for logger.

In short: how can I tell the app form some settings file, to log something specific only, for example just one class, or one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have needed to do a similar sort of thing. This is how I did it.

I created a category class and use that as a parameter when the logging object is initialised.

```
/// <summary>
/// Category object for logging
/// </summary>
public class Category
{
    #region Private Members
    private bool    m_active;
    private string  m_name;
    private bool    m_excludeFromLogFile = false;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a category and add it to the Logging category list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The Name of the category</param>
    /// <param name="active">The active state of the category</param>
    /// <param name="exclude">If true any messages for this category will not be written to the log file</param>
    /// <param name="addedToList">If true then the new category will be added to the logging category list</param>
    public Category(string name, bool active, bool exclude, bool addedToList)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_active = active;
        m_excludeFromLogFile = exclude;

        if(addedToList)
        {
            Log.GetInstance().AddCategory(this);
        }
    }

    #region Public Accessor Methods
        // .. Add accessors as required 
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see by the line  "Log.GetInstance().AddCategory(this);", my logging object is a singleton.

The singleton, has some methods to add and remove categories

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a new category to the list of available categories
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newCat">The category object to add</param>
public void AddCategory( Category newCat )
{
    // Ensure that the category doesn't already exist in the list
    if( this.m_CategoryList.Contains( newCat ) == false )
    {
        // Add the new category to the list
        this.m_CategoryList.Add( newCat );
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Remove a category to the list of available categories
/// </summary>
/// <param name="catName">The name of the category to be removed</param>
public void RemoveCategory( string catName )
{
    Category toRemove = null;

    // Iterate through the categories looking for a match
    foreach( Category cat in this.m_CategoryList)
    {
        // Compare the category names (case insensitive)
        if( cat.Name.ToUpper() == catName.ToUpper() )
        {
            // Assign the category to remove to a local variable and exit the loop
            toRemove = cat;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove the category if it's been located
    if( toRemove != null )
    {
        this.m_CategoryList.Remove( toRemove );
    }
}
```

When processing the log event it is now just a case of checking the active state of the category to see if that message is required.

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a log entry in the log file and then Fire an event for the log message to be handled
/// </summary>
/// <param name="category">The category to log the message against</param>
/// <param name="args"> Message logging arguments used by the event</param>
public void WriteLine(Category category, MessageEventArgs args)
{
    // Ensure that the category specified exists in the array list
    if( this.m_CategoryList.Contains( category ) )
    {
        // Ensure the category is active 
        if(category.Active == true)
        {
            if(!category.ExcludeFromLogFile)
            {
                // Try and log the message to the log file
                this.WriteLineToFile( category, args );
            }

            // Ensure an event handler has been assigned
            if(MessageEvent != null)
            {
                // This message event is handled by the UI thread for updating screen components.
                MessageEvent(category, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want the message to be displayed on a screen, you'll need to handle the message event in the UI thread. Here is a sample from one of my list view components...

```
private void ListViewLogging_MessageEvent(Category category, MessageEventArgs args)
{
    // Ensure the event was received in the UI thread
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        if(args.Message != null)
        {
            // We aren't in the UI thread so reFire the event using the main thread
            this.BeginInvoke(new MessageReceivedDelegate(this.ListViewLogging_MessageEvent), new object[]{category,args});
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // We are currently in the main thread.
        // Lock so no other thread can be handled until event processing has been finished
        lock(this)
        {
            // Create a new ListView item for the new message 
            ListViewItem newEntry = null;;

            // Determine the category type
            switch( category.Name )
            {
                case "Serious":
                {
                    // Serious error detected
                    if( args.Message.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        newEntry = new ListViewItem( new string[]{category.Name, args.Occurred.ToLongTimeString(), args.Message} );
                        newEntry.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "Warning":
                {
                    // Warning detected.
                    if( args.Message.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        newEntry = new ListViewItem( new string[]{category.Name, args.Occurred.ToLongTimeString(), args.Message} );
                        newEntry.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "Progress":
                {
                    // If a message has been specified, log it
                    if( args.Message.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        newEntry = new ListViewItem( new string[]{"", args.Occurred.ToLongTimeString(), args.Message} );
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "Debug":
                {
                    // Just a standard Debug event so just display the text on the screen
                    if( args.Message.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        newEntry = new ListViewItem( new string[]{category.Name, args.Occurred.ToLongTimeString(), args.Message} );
                        newEntry.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "Info":
                default:
                {
                    // Just a standard event so just display the text on the screen
                    if( args.Message.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        newEntry = new ListViewItem( new string[]{category.Name, args.Occurred.ToLongTimeString(), args.Message} );
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Add the item if it's been populated
            if( newEntry != null )
            {
                this.Items.Add( newEntry );
                this.EnsureVisible( this.Items.Count-1 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok and know how can you activate or deactivate the logging of specific event without changing and rebuilding the code?

Comment: You would need an accessor method to the Category container in the Logging object. Find the category and set the active state. An alternative would be to have some static categories by default (I use Serious, Warning, Info and Debug) and then have access methods to those specific categories.

Comment: at first i thougth about some mechanism, where in the setting file I could dynamicaly add class names, or method names and then run the application that coul read settings file (at start) and decide what to log... but this "layering" of logs in debug, warn etc can be helpfull too, thanks :)

Comment: I have to admit, I don't know a huge amount about Log4Net but in the one instance it had been included in one of our projects, it screwed everything up so we took it out and went back to using our singleton logging object.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at .NET Tracing. Here is a very short introduction (1 page):

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_debugging/tracing/article.php/c5919

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at Log4Net. Log4Net provides App.Config configuration of logging levels, redirects to multiple outputs, allows synchronous or asynchronous (buffered) logging.

A good article here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net

I wrote an article on how to use Regex Find and Replace to blanket change the logging throughout your application to use another syntax. Please see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925531/regular-expression-in-visual-studio-for-renaming-logging-method-parameter-string/8925622#8925622), and [this blog article](http://www.abtsoftware.co.uk/News/tabid/93/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/18/Visual_Studio_Productivity_The_power_of_Regex_Find_and_Replace.aspx).

Comment: yes as I wrote, i will take a look at it, and see what suites best for me. If i could check this answer as correct too, i would do it :) maybe after trying i will change my mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use log4net **logger**'s and **filter**'s. See [introduction article](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html)